# Efficient way to find and replace many strings in a large text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The Text file contains a software output on a time domain analysis. 10800 seconds simulation and 50 nodes being considered. We have 540,000 strings to be replaced in **540 MB text file with 4.5 million lines**.

Which is currently projected to take more than 4 days. Something is going wrong. Don't know what. Please suggest me a better efficient approach.

Below is the function which does the find and replace. 
To replace the string the script goes through the **original text file line by line** at the same time **it generates a duplicate file with replaced strings**. *So another 540 MB file with 4.5 million lines will be generated at the end of the script*.

```
Function ReplaceStringsInTextFile
{
    $OutputfilebyLine = New-Object -typename System.IO.StreamReader $inputFilePathFull
    $uPreviousValue = 0
    $time = 60
    $u = 0; $LastStringWithoutFindResult = 0
    $lineNumber = 0
    while ($null -ne ($line = $OutputfilebyLine.ReadLine())) {  
        $lineNumber = $lineNumber + 1
        if ($time -le $SimulationTimeSeconds)  # time simulation start and end checks 
        {

            # 10800 strings corresponds to one node 
            # there are 50 nodes.. Thus 540,000 values 

            # $StringsToFindFileContent contains strings to find 540,000 strings
            # $StringsToReplaceFileContent contains strings to replace 540,000 strings

            $StringToFindLineSplit = -split $StringsToFindFileContent[$time-60]
            $StringToReplaceLineSplit = -split $StringsToReplaceFileContent[$time-60]
            if($u -le $NumberofNodes-1)
            {
                $theNode = $Nodes_Ar[$u] 
                $StringToFindvalue = $StringToFindLineSplit[$u]
                $StringToReplacevalue = $StringToReplaceLineSplit[$u]
                if (($line -match $theNode) -And ($line -match $StringToFindvalue)){
                    $replacedLine = $line.replace($StringToFindvalue,$StringToReplacevalue) 

                    add-content -path $WriteOutputfilePathFull -value "$replacedLine"
                    $uPreviousValue = $u                      
                    $checkLineMatched = 1
                    if (($line -match $LastNodeInArray)) {
                        $time = $time + 1 
                        $LastStringWithoutFindResult = 0
                    }
                } elseIf (($line -match $LastNodeInArray) -And ($checkLineMatched -eq 0)) {
                    $LastStringWithoutFindResult =  $LastStringWithoutFindResult + 1
                } else { 
                    #"Printing lines without match"
                    add-content -path $WriteOutputfilePathFull -value "$line"
                    $checkLineMatched = 0
                }
            }

            if ($checkLineMatched -eq 1) {
                # incrementing the value of node index to next one in case the last node is found 
                $u = $uPreviousValue + 1
                if ($u -eq $Nodes_Ar.count) {
                        $u = 0
                        $timeElapsed = (get-date -displayhint time) - $startTime 
                        "$($timeElapsed.Hours) Hours $($timeElapsed.Minutes) Minutes $($timeElapsed.Seconds) Seconds"
                }
            }
        }
        # Checking if the search has failed for more than three cycles
        if ($LastStringWithoutFindResult -ge 5) { # showing error dialog in case of search error
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("StringToFind Search Fail. Please correct StringToFind values. Aborting now" , "Status" , 0)
            $OutputfilebyLine.close()
        }
    }   
    $OutputfilebyLine.close()
}
```

The above function is the last part of the script. Which is taking the most time. 
I had run the script in under 10 hours 1 year ago.

**Update** The script sped up running after 4 hours and suddenly time to complete projection reduced from 4 days to under 3 hours. The script finished running in 7 hours and 9 minutes. However i am not sure what made the sudden change in speed other than asking the question on stack overflow :)

Comment: What is `$StringToFindFileContent` and `$StringsToReplaceFileContent`? How big are they, how much churn will splitting them every matching line cause? Without knowing that, the only suggestion I have is to move `Add-Content` out of the loop; stream whichever new line is appropriate out of the loop and pipeline into `Add-Content` once at the end. Currently you're starting Add-Content and opening/closing the output file four million times.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler $StringToFindFileContent is 3.5 MB file with 50 strings in one line and 10800 lines in total  $StringsToReplaceFileContent is also similar 3.5 MB file with 50 strings in one line and 10800 lines in total.

Comment: I am currently in the process of running the script while i posted the question. Suddenly the speed seems to have picked up and the script is currently projected to finish in 2 hours 20 mins.  It has created 110 MB of the duplicate file with 420 MB remaining.

Comment: Your code is totally broken. There are closing brackets `}` just layin' around, messing up the code, variable names are long as hell, sometimes you are missing returns, brackets, there are nearly useless comments... Please clean your code to be a _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_. It's not meant to be offending, I just think if you clean up your code it will be easier - for you and for the community - to help you out with this.

Comment: @Clijsters I have cleaned up the code little bit. As of this moment the script has finished running. After about 4 hours in to running it sped up on its own. Projection before was the running will take more than 4 days to complete.  Instead the last part of the script finished in 7 hours and 9 minutes.

Comment: @RayBacker: Thanks for cleaning up. The following is however braking: At ln 9 is an `if` statement without a block, ln 31 same with `else`, ln 38, a `}`, same on ln 51, 85, and 62. This was what I meant by cleaning up. I didn't say, you are searching for a working code. I like it that you are asking for improvement tips and not for code-writing (y)

Comment: @RayBacker No it is __not__ a working one! `$inputFilePathFull` is never declared, `$StringToFindFileContent` is never declared, `$StringsToReplaceFileContent` is never declared, Line 9 `if ($time -le $SimulationTimeSeconds) # 10862 {` is invalid, the last line `}` is invalid, etc... Before you say the variables are set before execution, think about why functions can have input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion by https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler
I have avoided writing one line at a time using

```
add-content -path $WriteOutputfilePathFull -value "$replacedLine"
```

Instead i am now writing ten thousand lines at a time using add-content

```
$tenThousandLines = $tenThousandLines + "`n" + $replacedLine
```

And at the appropriate time I am using add-content to write 10,000 lines at one go like below. *The if block follows my methods logic*

```
 if ($lineNumber/10000 -gt $tenThousandCounter){
        clear-host
        add-content -path $WriteOffpipeOutputfilePathFull -value "$tenThousandLines"
        $tenThousandLines = ""
        $tenThousandCounter = $tenThousandCounter + 1
}
```

I have encountered system out of memmory exception error when trying to add 15,000 or 25,000 lines at a time. After using this the time required for the operation has **reduced from 7 hours to 5 hours. And at another time to 2 hours and 36 minutes**.